# How do I use boost library with WDK environment

Tags: boost, wdk

I wanna to compile my c plus plus project that using boost library with WDK rather than VisualStudio.

My computer's OS is Windows7-64bit, the WDK version is 7.6 and boost library version is 1.51

Once I compile my source code project, the WDK compiler will occure an error:

```
e:\lib\boost_1_51_0\boost\array.hpp(72) : error C2039: 'ptrdiff_t' : is not a member of 'std' .
```

Whole project's file contents are as follow:

File sources:

```
TARGETTYPE=PROGRAM
TARGETNAME=helloworld

UMENTRY=main
USE_MSVCRT=1
USE_NATIVE_EH=1

#
# use iostream package and STL
#
USE_IOSTREAM=1
USE_STL=1
STL_VER=70

#
# my boost library root directory
#
BOOST_INC_PATH=E:\lib\boost_1_51_0

INCLUDES=$(BOOST_INC_PATH)
TARGETLIBS=$(SDK_LIB_PATH)\user32.lib

SOURCES=HelloWorld.cpp

UMTYPE=console
UMBASE=0x4000000
```

File HelloWorld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp> 

void InvokeVector()
{
    //invoke STL's vector
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back("Entry ");
    vec.push_back("of ");
    vec.push_back("Vector");
    vec.push_back("……\n");
    //print vec
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<vec.at(i);
    }
}

void InvokeBoost()
{
    //invoke Boost's array<T, N>
    boost::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<"arr["<<i<<"]"<<"is" <<arr[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
//  InvokeVector();  //run normally
    InvokeBoost(); //it will occure an error
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please teach me how to solve this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt you can use boost "as is" with WDK, see the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718309/using-boost-in-wdk-build-environment-for-applications . However, you can try and patch the boost libraries you need.

Comment: Is your project a driver?  If not, why would you want to build it using the WDK?

Comment: Dear Igor R: I'm developing an dokan library user mode application, the dokan library ask for build with WDK but vs2010, so, I confusing how to build my dokan app in WDK environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But you can port some.

It's well explained here : [The NT Insider:Guest Article: C++ in an NT Driver](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=490)

> One of the main problems with C++ in the
>   kernel is that most of the "nice" features of the language are not
>   directly available in that mode. Some are easy to recreate and we will
>   see how to do that. However, some features should be forgotten such as
>   C++ exceptions, which are not the same as kernel exceptions.
>
> Such features have to be forgotten simply because there is no support
>   for them in kernel mode. Translation: does not compile. If you have
>   the time and energy you may attempt to port them to kernel mode, but
>   frankly, exceptions are too slow for kernel mode. This will have an
>   impact on your C++ coding style, which is something you should keep in
>   mind.

Comment: I want to run Dokan library's mirror.c sample in VS2010, but failed. So I follow the Dokan's official option to build mirror sample in WDK, but my user-mode app contain some C++ languange in it, and it's why I ask if there was someone make WDK support C++ before. http://dokan-dev.net/en/docs/

Answer (score 0):

longer answer - yes

just add

typedef  int            ptrdiff_t;

before pulling in boost headers and all will be well for basic boostness